# Transform stacked matrix into block-diagonal form

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, block-matrices

Consider two matrices $A$ and $B$ that get stacked to form a (tall) matrix $J$,

$$
J = \left[\begin{array}{l}
A\\
B
\end{array}
\right].
$$

Assume that $\text{rank}(J) = \text{rank}(A) + \text{rank}(B)$ holds (and usually $J$ is full rank). I am trying to show that there always exists a linear transform $T$ such that $JT$ has a kind of block-diagonal structure, i.e. that all columns of $AT$ with non-zero entries are stacked on top of columns with all zero entries of $BT$, and vice versa.

So far, I tried to explicitly construct this transformation from the left singular vectors of $A$ and $B$, but I couldn't yet get this to work. Any hint is much appreciated!

Comment: It’s easy to find a $T$ such that $JT$ has this form, but I don’t think it’s necessarily possible to find $T$ such that $TJ$ has this form

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ah, interesting! After closer inspection I realised that using JT would work equally well in my original problem (or even better). Edited the question accordingly. Why is T for JT easier to solve?

Comment: One approach that works is to row-reduce the transpose of $J$ into reduced row echelon form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $\operatorname{rank}(J) = \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$ tells you that the rows of $A$ are linearly independent to the rows of $B$. In other words, for all column vectors $x,y$ of the correct size: $A^\top x + B^\top y = 0$ implies that $A^\top x = B^\top y = 0$ (where $A^\top$ denotes the transpose of $A$). By applying row operations to $J^\top$, we can find an invertible matrix $S$ such that $SJ^\top$ is in reduced row-echelon form. Because of the independence condition, we can further conclude that
$$
SJ^\top = \pmatrix{R_1 & 0\\0 & R_2},
$$
where $\pmatrix{R_1\\0}$ has the same shape as $A^\top$, $\pmatrix{0\\R_2}$ has the same shape as $B^\top$, and both $R_1,R_2$ are in reduced row-echelon form. Taking the transpose of both sides, we see that
$$
JS^\top = \pmatrix{R_1^\top & 0\\0 & R_2^\top},
$$
which is to say that $S^\top$ brings the matrix $J$ into the desired form.